# /ci3/contact not found after ci3-fire-start installation

Tags: configuration, github, codeigniter

I installed apache2 on my ubuntu 16 and the localhost folder is located in /var/www/html/

Downloaded ci3-fire-starter and extracted the folder to /var/www/html/ci3-fire-starter-folder

I also followed the installation instruction; changing the base url to => http://localhost/ci3-fire-starter-folder
configured the database, gives permission to the folder and so on

However, I only managed to view the welcome page. But once I click on login button or contact or whatever, I got an error

[image: after clicking contact button]

is there any step(s) that I missed? Please help me

Comment: and that "ci3" is the folder name under /var/www/html